# change width of an inner Iframe that is inside 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, width

I need to change through javascript a width from an structure like this

```
    <div id="HTMLGroupBox742928" class="HTMLGroupBox" style="width:1366px">
         <div style ="width:800px;">
               <iframe id="notReliable_ChangeEveryTimeOnLoad" frambeborder="no" style="width:800px"> 
<html>....</html>
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can i set a width of 1366px for both the inner div and the iframe ? btw, the iframe Id keep changing on every load from the master program, so i gotta run around using other methods than getelementbyid...

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery :

```
$(".HTMLGroupBox").css("width","1366px"); // targets the first div with class HTMLGroupBox and sets its width.

$(".HTMLGroupBox").find('div').css("width","1366px"); // targets the div element inside the first div with class HTMLGroupBox and sets its width.

$(".HTMLGroupBox").find('div').find('iframe').css("width","1366px"); // targets the iframe element inside the div which is inside the first div with class HTMLGroupBox and sets its width.
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/ayL6o6v3/

In Javascript :

```
document.getElementByClass("HTMLGroupBox").style.width = "1366px";
document.getElementByClass("HTMLGroupBox").getElementsByTagName('input').style.width = "1366px";
document.getElementByClass("HTMLGroupBox").getElementsByTagName('input').getElementsByTagName('iframe').style.width = "1366px";
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/ayL6o6v3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, you should be doing something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="HTMLGroupBox742928" class="HTMLGroupBox" style="width:1366px">
     <!-- Use an ID on each component you want to change through JS -->
     <div id="innerDiv" style ="width:800px;">
         <iframe id="notReliable_ChangeEveryTimeOnLoad" frambeborder="no" style="width:800px">
         <html>....</html>
    </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('innerDiv').style.width = "1366px";
document.getElementById('notReliable_ChangeEveryTimeOnLoad').style.width = "1366px";
```